# Sending a variable to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have these 2 functions and would like 1 to execute the other with a specified variable:

```
function ckbmovestate() {
    $(this).css("-webkit-transform", "translate(53px, 0px)")

    };

function initcheckbox(){
    var togglebox = "<div class='toggle_box'><div class='switch'></div></div>";
    $('input[type=checkbox]').css('display','none');
    $('fieldset[data-input-type=checkbox]').append(togglebox);
    $('fieldset:has(:checkbox:checked)').each(function(){
        $(this).find('.switch').attr('data-state', 'on');
        ckbmovestate($(this))
    });
    $('fieldset:has(:checkbox:checked)')
    $('fieldset:not(:has(:checkbox:checked))').find('.switch').attr('data-state', 'off');

};
```

As you might guess, this does not work. Question is why? Could you give me a quick course on variable handling? Thanks guys, I know you are the best!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest option is to define your function to take a parameter:

```
function ckbmovestate(element) {
    $(element).css("-webkit-transform", "translate(53px, 0px)")
}
```

You can then call this with `ckbmovestate(this)` from your code.

---

If you really *want* to be able to use the `this` keyword within a function when it's called, you can do so.  It's not worth it here, but there may come a time when you want to do this.  To achieve this, you need to make use of [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Apply).  Here, either would work:

```
ckbmovestate.call(someElement);
```

This sends the value of `someElement` to `ckbmovestate`. Inside `ckbmovestate`, you will be able to access the value using the keyword `this`.  So in you code above, the following call would work:

```
ckbmovestate.call(this);
```

This is almost certainly overcomplicating things for this situation, however -- much easier to define a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

because you don't accept an argument in ckbmovestate

your ckbmovestate function should look like this if you don't want to change too much of your code:

```
function ckbmovestate(element){
   element.css("-webkit-transform", "translate(53px, 0px)");
}
```

If you often use the ckbmovestate function, I suggest you make your own little plugin of it, which you do like this;

```
$.fn.ckbmovestate = function(){
$(this).each(function(){
   $(this).css("-webkit-transform", "translate(53px, 0px)");
});
}
```

than, in the jquery each loop in your code in the question, you can write this:

```
 $('fieldset:has(:checkbox:checked)').each(function(){
        $(this).find('.switch').attr('data-state', 'on')
               .ckbmovestate();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the function to use a parameter.

```
function ckbmovestate( x ) {
    x.css("-webkit-transform", "translate(53px, 0px)")
};
```